# Typescript get T out of Array<T>, where T can be anything

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'll start with example code.

`toggle<K extends keyof T, V = T[K] extends any[] ? T[K] : never>(key: K, value: V): ...`

I call this function on array-like properties. Since `V` or `T[K]` is array-like type (eg. `string[]`), I want it to be just `string`. Note that it can be any array type.

Is this possible to get just `string` type out of `V`?

```
interface ITest {
  prop1: number;
  prop2: number[];
}
```

`T` is for example `ITest`
When key(`K`) is `prop2`, `V` should be `number`, else if key is `prop1`, `V` should be `never`

**Behaviour:**

`toggle("prop2", "string")` type error

`toggle("prop2", [1, 2])` type error

`toggle("prop2", 1)` valid

Comment: Hi, can you put in the question the whole code snippet, as you dont even provide variable `T` here.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use a lookup type with `number` as the property type:

```js
type ArrayComponent<A extends any[]> = A[number];
```

You can also do it using a conditional type with an [`infer`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) declaration:

```js
type ArrayComponent<A extends any[]> = A extends (infer U)[] ? U : never;
```

Either way, `ArrayComponent<V>` will be the component type when `V` is an array type.